# Get Ram and device info from regular class , android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

this is the main activity ,from which i am calling the class S ( where i am getting device info and ram

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

TextView  txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

S s= new S();
long value=s.mem();
txt.setText("sa"+value);

}
}
public class S extends Service
{
public long mem()
{
long value=0;
int id = android.os.Process.myPid();

ActivityManager activityManager=(ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

MemoryInfo outInfo=activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(new int[]{id})[0]; 

value=outInfo.getTotalPrivateDirty();

String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
String brand        = Build.BRAND;
String product      = Build.PRODUCT;
String model        = Build.MODEL;

String a = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

return value+manufacturer+brand+product+model+applicationName;
 }
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
 {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return new ServiceReaderDataBinder();
}

class ServiceReaderDataBinder extends Binder 
{
S getService(){ return S.this;}
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: It is not able to resolve "ACTIVITY_SERVICE and .getresource()" and when  i extend it with Service its giving  error (java.lang.runtimeException unable to start componentinfo, java.lang.nullpointer exception: attempt to invoke virtual method java.lang.object, android.content.context.getsystemservice (java.lang.string on anull object reference )

Comment: i want to get device info from S class, code is working fine when i run it in main activity but when i cal it with another java class i get above error, i need to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an instance of service but actually you should bind the service.Modify your activity something like below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Intent intent=new Intent(this, s.class);
        bindService(intent, conn, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

 }

 public ServiceConnection  conn=new ServiceConnection() {

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ServiceReaderDataBinder binder=(ServiceReaderDataBinder )service;
    s=binder.getService();
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt)).setText(s.mem());
}
};
```

Note:Dont forget to declare your service in menifest file